# Probability Scores threshold usually used in Deep Learning for an Object Recognition task

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a Faster RCNN project.

I have launched the algorithm and obtained all the bounding box proposals. Each one has a certain probability score:

[image]

My question is: What is the probability score threshold usually used by the Deep Learning scientific community in the Object Detection field in order to say if an object inside a bounding box belongs to a class ? Do you think that 60% is a good threshold ? 
The authors are using the Multi-Task loss:
[image: Multi-task loss]

Thank you very much for all your answers

Comment: You cannot choose a threshold without defining the utility/loss/cost function.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you very much for your answer. I am using the Multi-Task loss.

Comment: By the way, the link to the first image is: http://ammaitsao.blogspot.sg/2016/06/faster-rcnn.html
And the second one: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp17/cse252C-a/CSE252C_20170426.pdf
And the Faster-RCNN article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf
CrossValidated does not allow me to put more than 2 links in the post.